Necessary condition for $\mathrm{Re}\bigl(\sum_{k=1}^{2n} u_{\sigma(k)}z_k\bigr)$ to be maximal
Let $z_1, \ldots, z_{2n}$ and $u_1, \ldots, u_{2n}$ be complex numbers where $n \ge 1$.
We assume that

the absolute values of $z_k$ are pairwise distincts for $k = 1, \ldots, n$,
the $u_1, \ldots, u_{2n}$ are pairwise distincts,
for $k = 1, \ldots, n$, we have
$$ \overline{z_k} = z_{2n+1-k} \text{ and } \overline{u_k} = u_{2n+1-k} \text{ and } \lvert u_k \rvert = 1. $$

For all permutations $\sigma$ of $\{ 1, \ldots, 2n\}$, we put
$$ S(\sigma) = \mathrm{Re}\bigl(\sum_{k=1}^{2n} u_{\sigma(k)}z_k\bigr). $$
We have
$$ S(\sigma) = \sum_{k=1}^n \mathrm{Re}(u_{\sigma(k)}z_k + u_{\sigma(2n+1-k)}z_{2n+1-k}). $$
I'm looking for $\displaystyle \max_{\sigma \in S_{2n}} S(\sigma)$.
Using Sage, I notice that if $S(\sigma)$ is maximal, then
$$ \sigma(k) + \sigma(2n+1-k) = 2n+1 $$
for $n = 1, 2, 3$ and $4$, that is $\overline{u_{\sigma(k)}z_k} = u_{\sigma(2n+1-k)}z_{2n+1-k}$.
Is it true ?

by hypothesis one has $|z_1|=|z_{2n}|$ so the distinct thingy has to be modified appropriately to take into account that; also if for example $u_1=u_2$ then clearly you can switch $1$ and $2$ at will so the result cannot hold as stated - I think the correct question is that under the hypothesis, the maximum is always realized at one permutation with the property you claim

I add the hypothesis. that $u_1, \ldots, u_{2n}$ are pairwise distincts.
